# Как объеденить БД из PythonAnyWhere с сайтом на другом хостинге?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, веб-сайт

Всем привет. У меня такой вопрос. Есть бот, работает на хостинге pythonanywhere, имеется БД SQLite с пользователями, имеется ли возможность подключить данную БД к сайту на другом хостинге? Или уже лучше арендовать сервер?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под словами **подключить SQLite к сайту**?

Comment: Один из вариантов - синхронизация БД между двумя хостами. В инете есть по этой теме достаточно материала.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я имею ввиду, чтоб бд висела на хостинге с ботом, а я мог подрубить ее к сайту, который лежит на другом хостинге

Comment: @Assur, спасибо, гляну

Comment: pythonanywhere предоставляет `MySQL`, если что.